# UIImageView follow circular path in Single View Application, how?

Tags: ios, swift, path, geometry

I'm working on a single view application, not SpriteKit, in Swift, and I have a UIImageView called obstacle, that I want to follow a circular path (assume the circle diameter is 100).
How can this be done? Can anyone help me? I've seen lots of answers but they're all for people using SpriteKit, and other ones that I have found are in Objective-C and I can't find certain methods in Swift that they're referencing...
Thanks!

Comment: It's in Objective-C and I can't find certain functions/methods in Swift...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out following code

```
let curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable()
let circleContainer = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200) // change according to your needs
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(curvedPath, nil, circleContainer)

let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
animation.path = curvedPath

animation.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto
animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
animation.duration = 5.0

obstacle.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "animate position along path")
```

Comment: Thanks, that works just great! Do you know how I can make it rotate the opposite direction (counterclockwise)?

Answer (score 1):

Try out this code. You can rotate it to anti-clockwise or clockwise both. Just set UIBezierPath clockwise parameter as true or false as required.

```
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(view.frame), CGRectGetMidY(view.frame)), radius: 100, startAngle: 0, endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI)*2, clockwise: true)

    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")

    animation.path = circlePath.CGPath
    animation.duration = 4
    animation.additive = true
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE
    animation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced

    animation.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto
    view.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "orbit")
```